# I need to return all the possible combinations of k numbers in [1,n] elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

The code I have written:

```
l=[i for i in range(1,n+1)]
n=int(input())
k=int(input())
def solve(l,n,r,index,temp,i,ans):
     if index==r:
         ans.append(temp)
         return temp
     if i>=n:return
     temp[index]=l[i]
     solve(l,n,r,index+1,temp,i+1,ans)
     solve(l,n,r,index,temp,i+1,ans)
     return ans
q=solve(l,n,k,0,[0]*k,0,[])
print(q)
```

Input:

```
4
2
```

Expected output:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

My output:

```
[[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4]]
```

In the code if I print the temp during the execution in the solve function it is showing the right combinations but when I return it is showing like this `[[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4]]`
Someone help me with this. I have used the Include and exclude method to generate the combinations.

Comment: It looks like Python. It's definitely no C++. Please, prevent TAG SPAMMING which is considered as rude. Also, please, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Adding to @Scheff'sCat's comment, I see no Angular related operations. Please include only related tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 1):

you need to append `temp`'s copy, not `temp`, or when you change `temp`'s value, it also change the value in `ans`.

code:

```
def solve(l,n,r,index,temp,i,ans):
     if index==r:
         ans.append(temp.copy())
         return temp
     if i>=n:
         return
     temp[index]=l[i]
     solve(l,n,r,index+1,temp,i+1,ans)
     solve(l,n,r,index,temp,i+1,ans)
     return ans

n=4
k=2
l=[i for i in range(1,n+1)]
q=solve(l,n,k,0,[0]*k,0,[])
print(q)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(it.combinations(range(1, 5), r=2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```